# Target multiple IDs in JS

Tags: javascript

Bit of a JS novice so excuse the question, but I have two menu lists in which I want the images to change. It works with just one menu using the below JS

```
function changeImage(anything) {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = anything;
      }
```

But if I try to target two IDs using document.querySelectorAll("slider, slider 2"); it still only works with one IDs. Is there any way to target both IDs as I don't think

https://jsfiddle.net/hyt1xLkz/

Thanks!

Comment: use classes instead of id. `class='slider'` and then `document.getElementsByClassName('slider)`

Comment: querySelectorAll uses css selectors not id names, so you'd have to add hashes in front of the id name

Comment: To get all the elements in the querySelectorAll you can:
1. Add *#* before the names
2. Switch the ids from images to classes

If you decide to add classes to your images, remember that in your changeImage function you need to use getElementsByClassName method which (in this case) return array. So you'll need to go through each element of this array to update the src attribute. 

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a0g3srLh/

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be much more then adding a "#" infront of the id's in the querySelector as so

```
document.querySelectorAll("#slider, #slider2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#slider, #slider2");
```